# get the head of a sorted list in prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, head

I'm new Prolog and I'm stuck at this point.
How can I get the Head of this sorted list?

```
mylist(List,First) :-
   sort(List, Sorted),
   mylist(Sorted,First).
   mylist([H|_],H).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **unify the sorted list with `[First|_]`**:

```
mylist(List,First) :-
    sort(List,[First|_]).
```

So now Prolog will unify the right operand of `sort/2` with `[First|_]`. This means that if you call with `mylist([1,4,2,5],F)`, Prolog will call `sort([1,4,2,5],[F|_])`. Now Prolog will sort the list to `[1,2,4,5]` and unify `[1,2,4,5] = [F|_]`. Which succeeds since `[1,2,4,5] = [1|[2,4,5]]`. So `F = 1` and the wildcard is `[2,4,5]`.

Note that the predicate will only succeed, if the second argument of `sort/1` is a list with at least one element.

You can also use that `First` to do further processing. If you need **both a reference to the sorted list and its head** you can use:

```
mylist(List,First) :-
    sort(List,Sorted),
    Sorted = [First|_],
    %% further processing with Sorted and First.
```